# How do I convert a pixel location (x and y coordinates) from one Android device to other Android devices?

Tags: android

How do I convert a pixel location (x and y coordinates) from one Android device to other Android devices with different screen size and different resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method:  Divide x,y by the screen width and height resulting in a float from 0.0 to 1.0 and then multiply those 2 factors to 2nd device's screen width and height.