# How to get relative coordinate on a large screen if we have a coordinate for small screen in android

Tags: android

I have coordinates corresponding to screen resolution `600x400`. Now I want to get the relative position of this coordinate for the screen resolution `1280x800`. After getting the coordinates, I have to create a link on that coordinate.
.For example

Suppose I have a coordinate (5,5) for a 600*400 device resolution, so this coordinate will be at the left-bottom of the screen.Now i want to know what will be the relative coordinate of this on a 1280*800 screen resolution device so that it looks at the same position i.e bottom left of screen. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you supplying coordinated in dp or px?

Comment: i think you want to use for drawing something. but it doesnt matter for different resolutions. because all have same coordinate on screen.

Comment: I am getting coordinates in px.

Comment: can you show me your code for small screens..??

Comment: Please see my edited question  to understand my actual requirement

Comment: @Swati http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739730/is-canvas-in-android-proportional-on-different-devices

Comment: @Segi Thanks a lot for providing the link but i am not using canvas because i have lots of coordinate where i have to create a textview and that is clickable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302522/how-do-i-convert-a-pixel-location-x-and-y-coordinates-from-one-android-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sticking to what you asked ,you can get your new pixels as per follow

suppose the coordinates are `(6,4)` on `600*400` screen size, now calculate the % of x,y as per screen resolution ,as follow

```
(6 * 100 )/600 = 1%
```

and

```
(4* 100)/400 = 1%
```

now calculate the coordinates as per the new screen size as follow ,

```
(1 * 1280) /100 = 12.8
```

and

```
(1* 800) /100 = 8
```

so the coordinates in the new screen size are : (12.8, 8) which were previously (6,4) .

But there are better ways to go through in requirements like these , if you could be more specific with what you are actually doing.

Comment: I was looking for this.

Comment: Happy to help... But like I said before Share what is your real intention behind and you can get better solutions than this..

Comment: My actual task is to craete some links on imageview.I am getting links from webend.They have created virtual device on the website User will put some links on different position of the device and we have to show that link on our device whose resolution is higher than what they have taken.

Comment: Kwel, sounds like this solution would work well for you in this case!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is formula for converting dp to px, and px to dp based on screen density, so either way you can convert the coordinates appropriated to relative screen density.

```
public int doToPixel(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}


public int pixelToDP(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have a coordinate (5,5) for a 600*400 device resolution, so this coordinate will at the left-bottom of the screen.Now i want to know what will be the relative coordinate of this on a 1280*800 screen resolution device so that it looks at the same position i.e bottom left of screen.

Comment: Just give the layout_weight for your view as Left|Bottom and set margins as 5 you will get yor answer, this is what i can figure out at most with your above comment.

Comment: btw, (5,5) means x and y position in screen, which by no means represent bottom, left of screen instead it means Top, Left of screen 5 peixel from top and left.

Comment: the coordinates are not fixed,its dynamic.So,how can we give weight